# What is a word that denotes a seemingly upstanding (generally well-doing) citizen who is in reality a crook, cruel, or morally questionable?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a sort of 'Lucius Malfoy' character (from Harry Potter); someone who has a wealthy and respectable facade that disguises a criminal or prejudiced interior.  It doesn't have to necessarily be an adjective; a noun would also work. Thanks!

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: That Heartspring character is 'pious' for sure. Scare quotes signal the questionability.

Comment: *Jekyll and Hyde*, which isn't one word. Although *Malfoy* is.

Comment: Have you considered *politician*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin - this is some 4 months late... but what do you mean? 'Pious'?

Comment: By putting scare quotes around a word, we call attention to it. Labeling someone 'pious' says that looks can be deceiving. Apologies for the lateness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few words that come to mind:

[sanctimonious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanctimonious)

> hypocritically pious or devout

[phony](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phony) or [specious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specious)

> having a false look of truth or genuineness

[pretentious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious)

> expressive of affected, unwarranted, or exaggerated importance, worth, or stature

Comment: (accepted for _specious_)

Answer (score 1):

**Hypocrite** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypocrite)) Someone who practices hypocrisy, who pretends to hold beliefs, or whose actions are not consistent with their claimed beliefs.

**Pecksniff** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pecksniff)) A very hypocritical person.

**Tartuffe** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tartuffe)) A religious hypocrite.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Hypocricy is about actions that are inconsistent with previous statements, it's not really about character. This type of character will often be a hypocrite, but they're not synonyms.

Comment: "Jekyll and Hyde" are two words, other words that can be used are "duplicitous", "deceitful" etc.

Comment: I don't think "Jekyll and Hyde" even fits this. That's someone who is evil part of the time, nice at other times.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that there's a specific word for this yet. But it's not uncommon for the name of a person to become a word that refers to something they're famously associated with. Examples are *boycott*, *chauvinist*, and *gerrymander*.

So at the risk of angering about half the US population, I suggest that "Trump" could become a word for what you describe. His public persona is a rich and glamorous businessman, but he's associated with many crooked business dealings (not even counting possible involvement in the January 6 insurrection) and there are credible accounts that he has inflated his net worth on many occasions (while also deflating the values of some of his properties to avoid taxes).